# Highcharts MySQL Data Filtering

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, highcharts

I used the following code to generate a chart using highchat JS for stock management event.

## HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                
                title: {
                    text: 'Item Request Summary',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['']
                },
                yAxis: [{
                    title: {
                        text: 'Requests'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
            ],
            
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                plotOptions: {
                 column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

                series: []
            }

            $.getJSON("data", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
                options.series[2] = json[3];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
</script>

<div class="col-md-9">
    <h3 class="panel-title"> 
        <a href="<?= site_url('welcome') ?>"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Back to Home"></a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Item Request Summary</h3>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/highcharts.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/exporting.js'></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

## Model

```
function get_request_data()
{        
    $this->db->select('sur.update_stock_id, sus.branch_id, sus.request_no, sus.billed_date, store_branch.branch_name,
    si.item_id, si.item_name AS item,   tf.avqty,   sur.r_qty as r_qty, sur.ap_qty as ap_qty, 
    tf1.issued_qty');
    $this->db->from('store_update_request sur');
    $this->db->join('store_update_stock sus', 'sus.update_stock_id=sur.update_stock_id', 'left');       
    $this->db->join('store_branch', 'sus.branch_id=store_branch.branch_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('store_item si', 'sur.item=si.item_id', 'left');        
    
    $this->db->join('(select update_stock_id, item, is_qty AS issued_qty 
        from store_update_issue         
        where store_update_issue.status=1 
        ) AS tf1', 
        'si.item_id=tf1.item AND sur.update_stock_id = tf1.update_stock_id','left' );
                
    $this->db->join('(select item, sum(qty)  AS avqty 
        from store_update_stock_details             
        where store_update_stock_details.status=1 
        group by item) AS tf', 'si.item_id=tf.item', 'left');
    $this->db->where(array('sus.status' => 1));   
    
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
    return false;
}
```

## Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 
class Chart extends CI_Controller {
 
 public function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
 $this->load->model('data');
 }
  
 public function index()
 {
 $this->load->view('charts/chart');
 }
  
 public function data()
 {
    
 $data = $this->data->get_request_data();
  
 $category = array();
 $category['name'] = 'Item';
  
 $series1 = array();
 $series1['name'] = 'Request Qty';
  
 $series2 = array();
 $series2['name'] = 'Approved Qty';
  
 $series3 = array();
 $series3['name'] = 'Issued Qty';
  
 foreach ($data as $row)
 {
 $category['data'][] = $row->item;
 $series1['data'][] = $row->r_qty;
 $series2['data'][] = $row->ap_qty;
 $series3['data'][] = $row->issued_qty;
 }
  
 $result = array();
 array_push($result,$category);
 array_push($result,$series1);
 array_push($result,$series2);
 array_push($result,$series3);
  
 print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
 }
  
 }
```

The code is working properly and generate the follwing out put.
[image]

Then, I needs to apply filters for the chart. One is branch wise and other is billed date range wise. In my model these fields are as in "branch_name" & "billed_date".

What can do for in the code to get this disired output. Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: Hi @MCIT Trends, What do you exactly mean by applying filters for the chart? Also, could you provide a sample of your JSON structure?

Comment: You can create a form with some inputs then create an API to get data according to those inputs. Each time users change the inputs value, request to that API and re-draw chart with Highcharts

Comment: @ Canh. Yes you are correct. Can you show me an example in fiddle. ?
.